# Empty space inside of atoms

Tags: atomic-physics, vacuum, atoms, point-particles

Since most of the space between the nucleus and electron is empty space is that space in a vacuum?
I’ve not seen any info on this online or in textbooks does anyone have anything on this?

Comment: surprisingly for many people to learn, there is no such thing as empty space.

Comment: secondly, there are good reasons to think maybe point particles are not pointlike at all. At the very best, pointlike dynamics are an approximation to interactions. An electron for instance, has been shown to be remarkably spherical, at least in conjunction with its charge distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to physics.stackexchange! You have to ask yourself what a vacuum is. Classically it is a macroscopic concept associated with the absence of gas pressure. The question if there is a vacuum between the molecules of a gas is therefore meaningless. In - microscopic - quantum mechanics vacuum can only be defined as the absence of matter in a probabilistic sense. The probability of finding any kind of matter should be zero. As this us absolutely not the case inside an atom, there exists no vacuum inside it.